# One button to search from either first or second text box?

Tags: c#, sql

Below is the code to search for either name or the code. I want to know how can I use one button to search either the name or the code. So what I mean is if I leave name blank and search for code, the code should appear. Or if i search for name and leave code text box blank then name should display.

```
  Int32 Record;           
  Record = DisplayName(txtName.Text);      
  lblResult.Text = Record + " records found";
  txtName.Text = "";


  Int32 Record;
  Record = DisplayCode(txtCode.Text);
  lblResult.Text = Record + " records found";
  txtCode.Text = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Int32 Record; 

Record = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCode.Text) ? DisplayName(txtName.Text) :   DisplayCode(txtCode.Text)      
lblResult.Text = Record + " records found";
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Int32 Record;  
if(txtName.Text=="")
{
  if(txtCode.Text!="")
  {
  Record = DisplayCode(txtCode.Text);
  lblResult.Text = Record + " records found";
  txtCode.Text = "";
  }
  else
  {
   lblResult.Text = "enter name/code to search ";
  }
}
else
{         
  Record = DisplayName(txtName.Text);      
  lblResult.Text = Record + " records found";
  txtName.Text = "";
}
```